# C# regarding a parameter and running program

Tags: c#

I hope somebody can be of assistance, thank you in advance.
I am using C# to generate some simulation models for evaluating the medium stationary time of a request in a system and the degree of usage of that serving station from the system.
I am using a function to generate the required numbers:

```
 public double genTP(double miu)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            double u, x;
            u = (double)random.NextDouble();
            x = (-1 / miu) * Math.Log(1 - u);
            return x;
        }
```

This is the main:

```
        Program p1 = new Program();
        double NS = 1000000;
        double lambda = 4;
        double miu = 10;
        double STP = 0;
        double STS = 0;
        double STL = 0;
        double i = 1;
        double Ta = 0;
        double Tp = 0;
        double Dis = 0;
        do
        {
            Tp = p1.genTP(miu);
            STP += Tp;
            STS += Ta + Tp;
            Dis = p1.genDIS(lambda);
            if (Dis < Ta + Tp)
            {
                Ta = Ta + Tp - Dis;
            }
            else
            {
                STL += Dis - (Ta + Tp);
                Ta = 0;
            }
            i++;
        } while (i <= NS);
        Console.WriteLine(STS / NS);
        Console.WriteLine((STP/(STP+STL))*100);
```

---

1) The medium stationary time (which is r) returned is wrong, I get values like 0.09.. but I should get something like ~0.1665.. The algorithm is ok, I am 100% sure of that, I tried something like that in Matlab and it was good. Also the degree of usage (the last line) returned is ok (around ~39.89), only the r is wrong. Could it be a problem with the function, especially the random function that should generate a number?

---

2)Regarding my function genTP, if I change the parameter from double to int, then it returns 0 at the end. I used debugger to check why is that, and I saw that when the method calculates the value of x with (-1 / miu), this returns 0 automatically, I have tried to cast to double but with no result. I was thinking that this could be a source of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to create a static random field in the calculation class

```
 static Random random = new Random();
```

Now I can use it without thinking of quick succession and I don't need to give it as a function parameter (I'm not trying to say it works faster but just similar to mathematical notation)

Comment: This seemed to work, I declared static and it works like it should, thank you very much.

Comment: I generally don't like making `Random` static variables. `Random` isn't thread-safe - it's generally clearer if you make it obvious that you're only using it within a single thread. Follow the link in my answer for discussion of how to get a `Random` per thread where required, but otherwise I would just pass the reference into methods instead. Aside from anything else, that makes it clearer that the random number generator is effectively a dependency of the method.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I suppose it’s a question of compromise.  If there is a possibility to design a solution without additional random classes it’s preferable in the case of a too complicated algorithm that requires a lot of calculations. I think the idea of using a random wrapper is good otherwise.

Comment: @Shymep: My solution doesn't include any extra classes - it just passes the random number generator in where it's needed. Personally I think it's a clearer *and* safer solution, but it's a matter of taste...

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a new instance of `Random` each time you call `genTP`. If this is called multiple times in quick succession (as it is) then it will use the same seed each time. See [my article on random numbers](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) for more information.

Create a single instance of `Random` and pass it into the method:

```
private static double GenerateTP(Random random, double miu)
{
    double u = random.NextDouble();
    return (-1 / miu) * Math.Log(1 - u);
}
```

And...

```
Random random = new Random();
do
{
    double tp = GenerateTP(random, miu);
    ...
}
```

A few more suggestions:

- Declare your variables at the point of first use, with minimal scope
- Follow .NET naming conventions
- Don't make methods instance methods if they don't use any state

Comment: I made the method static, but when I inserted the code here, I forgot to remake the method how it was initially and change the main accordingly. Also, now I get way higher value, like ~128.943.. and also the second value is now kind of wrong, it is either a bit lower or a bit higher. The site you gave as a reference has an error, so I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: @Carmichael: I've fixed the link in the answer. Whatever else is wrong with your code, I doubt that you really wanted to get the same number each time...

Comment: I declared this  static Random random = new Random(); and with the help of your function, it now works, thank you very much.

Comment: @Carmichael: Generally speaking, that's not a good idea. `Random` isn't thread-safe; now you only have one thread in your code, but as a matter of principle I'd avoid making it static. Applying the change I suggested should have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, it is because the compiler does an integer division because they are two integers.
int / int = int (and the result is truncated).
If any of the args are floating point types, the operation is promoted to a floating point division. If you change your arg to an int, you should either use -1d (a double with value -1), or cast 'miu' to a double before usage:

```
x = (-1d / miu) ...
```

or

```
x = (-1 / (double)miu) ...
```

Or, of course, use them both as doubles. I prefer the first way.